# Select option in dropdown based on $_GET values in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select options in select drop down based on $_GET values. 
Right now I am using PHP to achieve this, by echoing 'selected' again and again for each and every option, but I have several values and I do not want to repeat the code several time.

Is there any way to achieve it in javascript or jquery, so that I do not have to 'selected' in separately in each and every option tag?

Code:

```
<div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" id="color" name="color_id[]" >
    <option value="1">White</option>
    <option value="2">Black</option>
    <option value="3">Grey</option>
    <option value="4">Yellow</option>
    <option value="5">Orange</option>
    <option value="6">Green</option>
    <option value="7">Blue</option>
           </select>
    </div>
```

`$_GET[color_id]` is an array of the selected values and it appears in the URL.

Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "5"
}
```

What I want??
Automatic 'selected' based on previous form submission ($_GET values present)

Comment: can you print your $_GET value and share with us?

Comment: @akcoban Added it

Comment: @Marium Malik what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @JohnnyB1988 I want to automatically select values in drop down based on $_GET, that is if color White, Black etc was selected by user and the values are present in URL, I want them to appear as selected in the drop down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (pure PHP solution):

```
<?php $myValues = array(
    "1" => "White",
    "2" => "Black",
    "3" => "Grey",
    "4" => "Yellow",
    "5" => "Orange",
    "6" => "Green",
    "7" => "Blue"
); ?>
<div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" id="color" name="color_id[]" >
        <?php foreach($myValues as $key => $val): ?>
            <?php $selected = $_GET['color_id'] == $key ? " selected='selected' " : ""; ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $value; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var valuesArray = <?php echo json_encode($_GET[color_id]); ?>;
$("#color").val(valuesArray);
```